# How to watch deep state change in component using pinia

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I'm having problems with watching **deep changes inside component**. My store looks like this (simplified):

```js
import {defineStore} from 'pinia'
import {PiniaAuth} from "@/store/piniaauth";
import {get, getDatabase, ref, set, update} from "firebase/database";
import {toRaw} from 'vue'
import {PiniaMainStore} from "@/store/pinia";

// useStore could be anything like useUser, useCart
// the first argument is a unique id of the store across your application
export const PiniaInfo = defineStore('info', {
    // arrow function recommended for full type inference
    state: () => {
        return {
            info: {
                name: 'John',
                bill: 10000,
            }
        }
    },
}
```

I need to **watch `bill` changes** and recount other data in component run methods. I've seen the function `storeToRefs` but didn't find how to watch if the data is in another object (in my case inside the `info` object).

Are there any ways to do this?

Comment: `info` is regular Vue reactive object, it can be watched like `watch(() => store.info, ..., { deep: true })`

Comment: Can it be done in watch method in component or it should be done in setup or outside of component script?

Comment: Anywhere. It's no different from any other Vue reactive value in this regard

Comment: How can it be done with options api?

Comment: With `watch` option. But with option api you've got Pinia map... helpers

Comment: Could you add an example, I tried and failed(

Comment: Here https://pinia.vuejs.org/api/modules/pinia.html#mapstate

Comment: Link to mapState is failing now ... it has changed to https://pinia.vuejs.org/api/modules/pinia.html#Functions-mapState